# Duplicate rows on ole db destination

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have quite a complex scenario where the same package can be run in parallel. In some situations both execution can end up trying to insert the same row into the destination, which causes a violation of primary key error.

There is currently a lookup that checks the destination table to see i the record exists so the insert is done on the its "no match" output. It doesnt prevent the error because the lookup is loaded on the package start thus both packages get the same data on it and if a row comes in both of them will consider it a "new" row so the first one succeeds and the second, fails.

Anything that can be done to avoid this scenario? Pretty much ignore the "duplicate rows" on the oledb destination? I cant use the MAX ERROR COUNT because the duplicate row is in a bath among other rows that were not on the first package and should be inserted.

Comment: Is this witha n Access Database or Exel Spreadsheet?

Comment: sql server both source and destination

Comment: can you not insert the PK?

Answer (score 2):

The default lookup behaviour is to employ Full Cache mode. As you have observed, during the package validation stage, it will pull all the lookup values into an local memory cache and use that which results in it missing updates to the table.

For your scenario, I would try changing the cache mode to `None` (partial is the other option). None indicates that an actual query should be fired off to the target database for every row that passes through. Depending on your data volume or a poorly performing query, that can have a not-insignificant impact on the destination. It still won't guarantee that the parallel instance isn't trying the to load the exact same record (or that the parallel run has already satisfied their lookup and is ready to write to the target table) but it should improve the situation.

If you cannot control the package executions such that the concurrent dataflows are firing, then you should look at re-architecting the approach (write to partitions and swap in, use something to lock resources, stage all the data and use a TSQL merge etc)

Comment: thanks man, thought of that but I should have mentioned that the dataset in question may contain more than 1M rows so partial cache is not an option. To make it worst, they have very sparse values, so not even the no match cache percentage would avoid 1M selects on the database

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought ... How about writing the new records to a temp table and merging it intermittently? This will give an opportunity to filter out duplicates.